# Inserting shortcode [stream /] into a Text widget

Tags: widgets, shortcode

hi i'm trying to insert a short code into a Text widget but all its doing it showing the code and not processing it.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(' [stream embed=false share=false width=500 height=560 dock=true controlbar=bottom bandwidth=high autostart=false playlistfile=http://www.xxx.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/playlist.xml config=http://www.xxx.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/config_for_playlist.xml playlist=bottom repeat=none /] '); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the text widget doesn't do php....

Here's my fave solution

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/

It's from Otto, so ya know it's good. Based heavily on the text widget, but allows for php

Answer (score 3):

if `[stream /]` is 'real' shortcode (not everything in square bracket is [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)) then try to add this to functions.php of your theme:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

related: [Stream Video Player does not work with do_shortcode()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/stream-video-player-does-not-work-with-do-shortcode) ?